# Evaluate $7\int xe^{6x^2}dx$ using u substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

5.3

Can somebody verify this solution for me? Thanks!

Evaluate $7\int xe^{6x^2}dx$ using u substitution

---

Let $u=6x^2$. Then $\frac{du}{dx}=12x$ and so $\frac{du}{12x}=dx$. Thus we have:

$7 \int xe^{6x^2}dx$

$=7 \int xe^u \frac{du}{12x}$

$= \frac{7}{12} \int e^u du$

$=\frac {7}{12} e^u + C$

$=\frac{7}{12} e^{6x^2} + C$

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: The way to check if an antiderivative is correct is to take the derivative and see if it gives the function to be integrated.